# RequestHandlerRetryAdvice | Service Activator

Tags: spring-integration

I want to block the retry from my of service activator, incase of any exception thrown.

Below is my configuration,

```
<http:inbound-gateway id="inboundGW"
        request-channel="getCustInfo" supported-methods="GET"
        error-channel="errorHandlerRouterChannel" 
        path="/Messages/{cust}" reply-channel="msgRetrival">
        <http:header name="cust" expression="#pathVariables.cust" />
    </http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator input-channel="getCustInfo"
    output-channel="msgRetrival" ref="createService" method="processCustInfo">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <ref bean="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession"></ref>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<bean id="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <property name="retryTemplate">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                      <property name="retryPolicy">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                            <property name="maxAttempts" value="1" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="recoveryCallback">
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                    <constructor-arg ref="errorHandlerRouterChannel"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
</bean>
```

Exception thrown from my service activator doesn't get caught by the error-channel specified in the http:inbound-gateway

Answer (score 1):

Spring integration config file was loaded twice in the deployment descriptor. After fixing this the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

If you want to throw the exception after retries are exhausted, remove the `recoveryCallback`.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, Thanks for the reply.  I have removed the recoveryCallback from the configuration.
Below are my finding from debugging the application,

1. Even if I set the "maxAttempts" to 1, I am observing that it retries 2 times.
2. When I handle the exception in my error-channel, the custom exception which I throw in my service activator gets converted to 
org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AggregateMessageDeliveryException. 
 And the list had two custom exceptions.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your configuration; that exception (and your 2 delivery attempts) implies that you have 2 subscribers on the `getCustInfo` channel. We only aggregate exceptions that way if we try each subscriber and they all fail. Perhaps you are loading the context twice somehow, creating 2 instances of the service activator? In any case a DEBUG log will show what is happening.

Comment: A common mistake with web apps is to load the config in both the root `ContextLoaderListener` and the `DispatherServlet` contexts.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell I was loading the config twice, after fixing this, the issue was resolved.